# how to convert string array of mixed data types

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, converters, mixed

Let's say I have read and loaded a file into a 2D matrix of mixed data as strings(an example has been provided below)

```
# an example row of the matrix
['529997' '46623448' '2122110124' '2310' '2054' '2' '66' '' '2010/11/03-12:42:08' '26' 'CLEARING' '781' '30' '3' '0' '0' '1']
```

I want to convert this chunk of data into their data types to be able to do statistical analysis on it with numpy and scipy.

The datatype for all of the columns is integer **except** the 8th index this is DateTime and the 10th index is pure string.

#### Question:

What is the easiest way to this conversation?

---

## EDIT

Performance is very important than readability, I have to convert **4.5m** rows of data and then process them!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? And what about the empty string?

Comment: @Kasramvd those are N/A integers, 0 or -1 will be replaced with the empty values. as I said `The datatype for all of the columns is integer except the 8th index this is DateTime and the 10th index is pure string.`

Comment: You have an empty sting in 7th index, (although your items are not separate with comma!) so you want to change that empty string to what?

Comment: @Kasramvd the shown row is the result of `print mtx[0]`! it's already been loaded, no need to have a `,` separator! **`so you want to change that empty string to what?`:** to 0.

Comment: How did you load this?  Have you tried `np.genfromtxt` with `dtype=None`?  What kind of processing will you do next?

Comment: @hpaulj **What kind of processing will you do next?** statistical and pre-processing the data to be trained with NN. **How did you load this?** `csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')]);`

Comment: Quoted strings that also contain the delimiter are better handled by `cvs`.  Without those the `numpy` or `pandas` readers handle conversion to numbers better.  There are lots of SO questions about those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like clear code like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

input_row = ['529997', '46623448', '2122110124', '2310', '2054',
             '2', '66', '', '2010/11/03-12:42:08', '26',
             'CLEARING', '781', '30', '3', '0', '0', '1']

_date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")
# only necessary because '' should be treated as 0
_int  = lambda x: int('0' + x)

# specify the type parsers for each column
parsers = 8 * [_int] + [_date, _int, str] + 6 * [_int]

output_row = [parse(input) for parse, input in zip(parsers, input_row)]
```

Depending on your needs, use an iterator instead of a list. This could greatly reduce the amount of memory you need.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer for the sake of its readability, although the @Kasramvd's answer is valid too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one linear with list comprehension:

```
In [24]: from datetime import datetime
In [25]: func = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")
In [26]: [{8:func, 10:str}.get(ind)(item) if ind in {8, 10} else int(item or '0') for ind, item in enumerate(lst)]
Out[26]: 
[529997,
 46623448,
 2122110124,
 2310,
 2054,
 2,
 66,
 0,
 datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 3, 12, 42, 8),
 26,
 'CLEARING',
 781,
 30,
 3,
 0,
 0,
 1]
```

Comment: I know I can apply this with a `for` to convert my `1m-row` matrix. just wondering, is there any method to expand this solution to convert the entire matrix? nice solution btw. +1

Comment: @Dariush I don't recommend this approach for every problem, If you don't care about the performance, note that readability is more important and you can simply implement it with a regular loop. Also another problem with this solution is that you can't handle the unexpected exceptions that might happen during the execution, for example TypeErros or etc.

Comment: performance is very important than readability, I have to convert 4.5m data! and the process them! so knowing this fact do you recommend this solution?

Comment: @Dariush: Converting probably takes a fraction of the time it takes to read the data from disk, so I wouldn't bother too much unless you see at the end that it is a problem.

Comment: @Dariush So why don't you use `Numby` or `pandas` for handling your data, and converting them during the load time. Which is extremely faster than python.

Comment: I went after `numpy` and `pandas` but I couldn't figure the way how to convert such a custom data like mine and didn't want to spend my entire afternoon to dig it up, so I have decided to move on the way I already know, but I am open this suggestion of yours if you know a way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed the following function to convert the 4.5m rows of the matrix, the invalid data type exception is also taken into consideration too. Although it can be improved with parallelizing the process, but it did the job OK for me, for what it worth, I am going to post it here.

```
def cnvt_data(mat):
    from datetime import datetime

    _date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")
    # only necessary because '' should be treated as 0
    _int  = lambda x: int('0' + x)

    # specify the type parsers for each column
    parsers = 8 * [_int] + [_date, _int, str] + 6 * [_int]

    def try_parse(parse, value, _def):
        try:
            return parse(value), True
        except ValueError:
            return _def, False

    matrix = [];

    for idx in range(len(mat)):
        try:
            row = mat[idx]
            matrix.append(np.asarray([parse(input) for parse, input in zip(parsers, row)]))
        except ValueError:
            l = [];
            matrix.append([])
            for _idx, args in enumerate(zip(parsers, row)):
                val, pres = try_parse(args[0], args[1], 0)
                matrix[-1].append(val)
                if(not pres): l.append(_idx);
            print "\r[Error] value error @row %d @indices(%s): replaced with 0" %(idx, ', '.join(str(x) for x in l))

        print "\r[.] %d%% converted" %(idx * 100/len(mat)),

    print "\r[+] 100% converted."

    return matrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually when people ask about reading `csv` files we ask for a sample of the file.  I've attempted to reconstruct your line from the string list:

```
In [590]: txt
Out[590]: b'529997, 46623448, 2122110124, 2310, 2054, 2, 66, , 2010/11/03-12:42:08, 26, CLEARING, 781, 30, 3, 0, 0, 1'
```

(`b` for bytestring in Py3, which is how genfromtxt expects its input)

`genfromtxt` expects a filename, open file, or anything that feeds it lines.  So a list of lines works fine:

With `dtype=None` it deduces column types.

```
In [591]: data=np.genfromtxt([txt], dtype=None, delimiter=',', autostrip=True)
In [592]: data
Out[592]: 
array((529997, 46623448, 2122110124, 2310, 2054, 2, 66, False, b'2010/11/03-12:42:08', 26, b'CLEARING', 781, 30, 3, 0, 0, 1), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4'), ('f6', '<i4'), ('f7', '?'), ('f8', 'S19'), ('f9', '<i4'), ('f10', 'S8'), ('f11', '<i4'), ('f12', '<i4'), ('f13', '<i4'), ('f14', '<i4'), ('f15', '<i4'), ('f16', '<i4')])
```

The result is a bunch of `int` fields, 2 string fields.  The blank is interpreted as boolean.

If I spell out the columns types I get a slightly different array

```
In [593]: dt=[int,int,int,int,int,int,int,float,'U20',int, 'U10',int,int,int,int,int,int]
In [594]: data=np.genfromtxt([txt], dtype=dt, delimiter=',', autostrip=True)
In [595]: data
Out[595]: 
array((529997, 46623448, 2122110124, 2310, 2054, 2, 66, nan, '2010/11/03-12:42:08', 26, 'CLEARING', 781, 30, 3, 0, 0, 1), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4'), ('f6', '<i4'), ('f7', '<f8'), ('f8', '<U20'), ('f9', '<i4'), ('f10', '<U10'), ('f11', '<i4'), ('f12', '<i4'), ('f13', '<i4'), ('f14', '<i4'), ('f15', '<i4'), ('f16', '<i4')])
```

I specified `float` for the blank column, which it then interprets as `nan`.  Handling of blacks can be refined.

I changed the string files to unicode (the default py3 string).

I should be able to specify a datetime conversion, for example to `np.datetime64`.

With just one line, `data` is a single element array, 0d, with a compound `dtype`.

Fields are accessed by name

```
In [598]: data['f8']
Out[598]: 
array('2010/11/03-12:42:08', 
      dtype='<U20')
In [599]: data['f2']
Out[599]: array(2122110124)
```

Speed wise this probably is the same as your custom reader.  `genfromtxt` reads the file line by line, and parses it.  It collects the parsed lines in a list, and creates an array once at the end (I don't recall if parsed lines are lists or dtype arrays - I suspect lists, but would have to study the code).

To handle the date, I have to use `'datetime64[s]'`, and some how change the date to read `"2010-11-03T12:42:08"`, probably in a `converter`.

===================

I can make a converter based on your `datetime` parsing:

```
In [649]: from datetime import datetime
In [650]: dateconvert=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.decode(),"%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S")
In [651]: data=np.genfromtxt([txt], dtype=dt, delimiter=',',  autostrip=True, converters={8:dateconvert})
In [652]: data
Out[652]: 
array((529997, 46623448, 2122110124, 2310, 2054, 2, 66, nan, datetime.datetime(2010, 11, 3, 12, 42, 8), 26, 'CLEARING', 781, 30, 3, 0, 0, 1), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4'), ('f6', '<i4'), ('f7', '<f8'), ('f8', '<M8[s]'), ('f9', '<i4'), ('f10', '<U10'), ('f11', '<i4'), ('f12', '<i4'), ('f13', '<i4'), ('f14', '<i4'), ('f15', '<i4'), ('f16', '<i4')])
```